# Why does the "T=0" method to calculate tangent work?

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

Given a random equation of a curve: $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$.
Suppose we need to find the tangent to this curve at any point $A(x_1, y_1)$. A method given to me by my professor was the 'T' method:

> The 'T' form of an equation can be obtained by replacing:
>   $$x^2 \rightarrow xx_1$$
>   $$y^2 \rightarrow yy_1$$
>   $$x \rightarrow \frac{x + x_1}{2}$$
>   $$y \rightarrow \frac{y + y_1}{2}$$
>   $$xy \rightarrow \frac{xy_1 + x_1y}{2}$$

The tangent to the curve is then the equation $T=0$.

For instance, if we need to find the tangent at $(2, 2)$ to the parabola $y^2 - 2x=0$:
$T =0$: $\implies yy_1 - 2\frac{x+x_1}{2} = 0$

Substituting $x_1 = 2$ and $y_1 = 2$: $$2y - (x+2) = 0$$ $$\implies 2y - x = 2$$

which is the required tangent.

**I don't understand how this *works*! Could someone help me understand why it does?**

---

This also works for other cases like:

- Deriving the equation of the two tangents to a curve from a certain external point: $SS_1 = T^2$ (S is the equation of the curve and S1 is the value given by the equation when the point is substituted into it (the power of the point wrt the curve))

Comment: Find Tangent concept here : https://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone

Comment: [A good reference](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you probably know that the tangent at $x_0$ of the parabola $y=ax^2$ is:
$$
y = ax_0^2 + 2ax_0(x-x_0).
$$

If you didn't know this, keep reading! This means that, if we stay "close enough" to $x_0$, the line above is the one that approximates best the direction of the parabola.

In particular, if we move from $x_0$ to $x_0 + \Delta x$, we get:
$$
a(x_0+\Delta x)^2 = ax_0^2 + 2ax_0\Delta x + a(\Delta x)^2.
$$

You see that if $\Delta x$ is very small, the last term tends to vanish, and 
$$
a(x_0+\Delta x)^2 \approx ax_0^2 + 2ax_0\Delta x 
$$

becomes a very good approximation. Since $\Delta x = x-x_0$, the equation of the line given by:
$$
y = ax_0^2 + 2ax_0(x-x_0)
$$

is the equation of our desired tangent.

Your "T-formula" implies that a curve $C$ with equation:
$$
ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2 gx +2 fy + c =0
$$

has tangent $T$ in $(x_0,y_0)$:
$$
axx_0 + h(xy_0+x_0y) + byy_0 + g(x+x_0) + f(y+y_0) +c=0.
$$

We would like to show now that $T$ is *tangent*, that is, that $T$ is the best possible approximation of $C$ if we stay "close enough" to the point.

If we move from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x_0+\Delta x, y_0+\Delta y)$, like before, we get:
$$
a(x_0+\Delta x)^2 + 2h(x_0+\Delta x)(y_0+\Delta y) + b(y_0+\Delta y)^2 + 2 g(x_0+\Delta x) +2 f(y_0+\Delta y) + c =0.
$$

Expanding the products:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
a(x_0^2+2x_0\Delta x+\Delta x^2)+ \\ 
+ 2h(x_0y_0+\Delta xy_0+x_0\Delta y+\Delta x\Delta y)+ \\
+ b(y_0^2+2y_0\Delta y+\Delta y^2)+ \\
+ 2 g(x_0+\Delta x) +\\
+2 f(y_0+\Delta y) + c =0.
\end{array}
$$

Like before, we can neglect the quadratic "small" terms to get a *linear* equation, which approximates our curve in the best way possible. We obtain:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
a(x_0^2+2x_0\Delta x)
+ 2h(x_0y_0+\Delta xy_0+x_0\Delta y)
+ b(y_0^2+2y_0\Delta y)+ \\
+ 2 g(x_0+\Delta x) 
+2 f(y_0+\Delta y) + c =0.
\end{array}
$$

To get the equation in $x,y$ for the line, we must (like before) replace $\Delta x$ with $(x-x_0)$, and now also $\Delta y$ with $(y-y_0)$. So:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
a(x_0^2+2x_0(x-x_0))
+ 2h(x_0y_0+(x-x_0)y_0+x_0(y-y_0))
+ b(y_0^2+2y_0(y-y_0))+ \\
+ 2 g(x_0+x-x_0) 
+2 f(y_0+y-y_0) + c =0.
\end{array}
$$

Summing, we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c}
a(-x_0^2+2x_0x)
+ 2h(-x_0y_0+xy_0+x_0y)
+ b(-y_0^2+2y_0y)+ \\
+ 2 gx 
+2 fy + c =0.
\end{array}
$$

This is an equation for the line, but we still haven't used the fact that the line *must pass* through our point $(x_0,y_0)$. Or, we still have to ensure that $(x_0,y_0)$ satisfies the equation for $C$. Now, we rewrite the expression above in the following way (we have moved the terms in $a,h,c$, and added and subtracted the terms in g,f,c):
$$
\begin{array}{c}
a(2x_0x)
+ 2h(xy_0+x_0y)
+ b(2y_0y)
+ g(x +x_0)
+ f(y+y_0) + 2c +\\
-(ax_0^2+2hx_0y_0+by_0^2+gx_0+fy_0+c) =0.
\end{array}
$$

Saying that $(x_0,y_0)$ passes through $C$ is saying that the second line vanishes! So we are finally left with:
$$
2ax_0x
+ 2h(xy_0+x_0y)
+ 2by_0y
+ g(x +x_0)
+ f(y+y_0) + 2c =0.
$$

Dividing both sides by $2$, we get exactly your formula.

(Yes, it is a rather long and complicated process. I can't come up with a simpler one that doesn't lose clarity and doesn't use advanced calculus. This is probably why they never prove it in high school!
Anyway, I'd be very very happy to see a shorter, elementary proof.)

Comment: Ah, so it was basically just taking an infinitesimally small increment in the coordinates. Thanks a lot! I'd like to see the calculus proof as well. Hopefully it isn't above my level right now.

Comment: @mikhailcazi Try yourself with calculus! 
You probably recognized that what I did with the $\Delta x$ is exactly differentiation. First try to find the tangent to $y=ax^2$ by deriving. Then try with the general formula. If you have trouble, ask again!

Comment: Haha, since you said 'advanced calculus', I thought it may be something above what I've learnt till date. I surely will try, though. :)

Comment: @mikhailcazi It's because I think you can use more advanced methods than simple derivatives, to shorten the proof. Anyway, with simple derivatives, remember that the equation of the tangent is $(y-y_0)/(x-x_0)=dy/dx$ (can you see why?).

Comment: Oh, that was really easy. Just differentiate, rearrange and you get it. I feel stupid that I even asked this question. xD Haha :P Tried for a random curve $ax^2 + by^2 + ....$ too; it was lengthy but worked out in the end.

Comment: @mikhailcazi It's not a stupid question, it is quite interesting actually. I bet everyone has seen it in high school, it is always presented as "powerful but arcane", and I had never seen a proof anywhere. Anyway, with calculus and linear algebra, you'll see that there will be no secrets left in high school math!

Comment: Yeah, it just struck me that I hadn't seen any proof. Anyway, thanks again! :)

Answer (score 10):

While geodude's method works, I'm putting up my calculus version of the problem.

Taking the random curve: $ax^2 + 2hxy + by^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$

Differentiating it wrt x:
$$2ax + 2hx\frac{dy}{dx} + 2hy + 2by\frac{dy}{dx} + 2g + 2f\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$
$$\implies (ax + hy + g) + \frac{dy}{dx}(hx + by + f) = 0$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{(ax + hy + g)}{(hx + by + f)}$$

The equation of the tangent at the point $(x_1, y_1)$ is: $(y-y_1) = \frac{dy}{dx} (x - x_1)$

$$\implies (y-y_1)(hx+by+f) = (x_1 - x)(ax + hy + g)$$
$$\implies hxy + by^2 + fy -hxy_1 - byy_1 - fy_1 = axx_1 + hyx_1 + gx_1 - ax^2 - hxy - gx$$

Rearranging:
$$ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + gx + fy = axx_1 + hyx_1 + gx_1 + hxy_1 + byy_1 + fy_1$$

Adding $gx + fy + c$ on both sides:
$$ax^2 + by^2 + 2hxy + 2gx + 2fy +c = axx_1 + hyx_1 + gx_1 + hxy_1 + byy_1 + fy_1 +gx + fy + c$$

The LHS is $0$.

$$\therefore axx_1 + 2h\bigg(\frac{x_1y + xy_1}{2}\bigg) + byy_1 + 2g\bigg(\frac{x_1 + x}{2}\bigg) + 2f\bigg(\frac{y + y_1}{2}\bigg) + c = 0$$

Which is the "T" form of the equation.

Comment: Yep, you got it.

Comment: What if $hx+by+f=0$ at $x=x_1,y=y_1$?

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is incorrect because of the fact that rather than using $(x_1,y_1)$ in calculation of $\frac{dy}{dx}$, you kept it in terms of general (x,y) (you confused a particular point on the curve and a general point in space or you used same variables for two different points). I have posted my explanation and the correct solution for the approach you want. Also @SufaidSaleel I have answered your question in my post. Check it out and tell me if you find an issue

Answer (score 0):

Replying to OP's answer: (let us keep the original 2 degree curve equation to be S and when you substitute ($x_1,y_1$), let it be be $S_1$). Also, I am pretty sure OP might have understood his mistake till now, but just for clarification, his solution is incorrect.
In his solution, he has taken $\frac{dy}{dx}$ to be in terms of x,y and substituted them in the equation $(y-y_1) = \frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$, while you have to substitute them in terms of $(x_1,y_1)$, what I mean is that they should not be kept in general terms (x,y) (line equation contains y = mx+c where (x,y) are general points on line) and should be dependent upon point of contact of tangent to the curve. He then proceeded to open the equation $(y-y_1) = \frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$ where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ was still in (x,y) terms and then added gx + fy + c on both sides and used $S_1 = 0$, which is wrong because gx + fy + c is a general point in 2D space and not necessarily on the curve (because he confused $(x_1,y_1)$ with (x,y) in the original portion of the equation $((y-y_1) = \frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1))$ he could successfully do this and get the final answer as $T = 0)$;
The real solution is along the same lines:

$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{(ax_1 +hy_1 + g)}{(hx_1 + by_1 + f)}$

Then using $(y-y_1) = \frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$ and opening up the equation, we get:
$hyx_1 + byy_1 + fy - hx_1y_1 - b(y_1)^2 - fy_1 = -axx_1-hxy_1-gx+a(x_1)^2 + hx_1y_1 + gx_1$

Rearrange to get $axx_1 + byy_1 + hxy_1 + hyx_1 + gx + fy = a(x_1)^2 + b(y_1)^2 + 2hx_1y_1 + gx_1 + fy_1$

Now you can add $gx_1 + fy_1 + c$ (on both sides as they are constants) to get (by using $S_1$ = 0) $T = 0$;

As for the comment below OP's answer by @Sufaid Saleel as to what would happen if $hx_1 + by_1 + f = 0$ (then we obviously cannot divide by it to get $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{(ax_1 +hy_1 + g)}{(hx_1 + by_1 + f)}$

So what we could do is take 2 cases, one where $ax_1 + hy_1 + g = 0$ and one where it is $\neq 0$ :

For the first case, a little bit of manipulation(multiplying first equation by $x_1$ and second equation by $y_1$ and adding and using $a(x_1)^2 + b(y_1)^ + 2hx_1y_1 .. = 0$ (this allows for more cases like $x_1 = 0 \& y_1 = 0$ and stuff like that, but they are cases which can be easily solved) shows that Δ of the given equation is $0$, implying that this is a pair of straight lines and you successfully found out the point of intersection of the two line $(x_1,y_1)$ (as you set both $\frac{∂S}{∂x}$ and $\frac{∂S}{∂y}  = 0$ which gives the centre of the conic (or if it is a pair of straight lines - the point of intersection of both lines))

If $ax_1 + hy_1 + g \neq 0 \implies$ there is a vertical tangent to the curve at that point (as the equation $ax_1 + hy_1 + g + \frac{dy}{dx}$$(by_1 + hx_1 + f)$ has to be equal to $0$ at that point, but the term with $\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \implies \frac{dy}{dx}$ has to be ∞ (positive or negative) (like the curve $2x^2 + 2y^2 + 6xy + 3x + 2y + 3 = 0$ has a vertical tangent at (-1,1)).