# Tangent of $Ax^2+By^2+2Hxy+2Gx+2Fy=0$

Tags: plane-geometry

Need to prove that the equation of the line tangent to $Ax^2+By^2+2Hxy+2Gx+2Fy=0$ at $P(x_1,y_1)$ is $Axx_1+Byy_1+H(xy_1+yx_1)+G(x+x_1)+F(y+y_1)+C=0$

I don't know where to start.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/721150/782505) might help you.